# Redshift SQL to store duration column in redshift and covert into seconds

Tags: sql, time, amazon-redshift

I have duration data coming from api and loading into redshift. For example if a car has travelled for

---> 1 day 4 hours 30 mins and 4 seconds and 85 micro seconds, the data will be 1.04:30:04.8530000

---> if a car travelled for 1 hour 30 mins and 4 seconds, the data will be 1:30:04

I want to store original data and also i want to convert this into seconds and store as a separate column.

Do you know

1. which data type i can use to store the original data (1.04:30:04.8530000/01:30:04)
2. how can i convert to seconds and which data type i can use for seconds.

Please advise.

thanks!

Comment: I would strongly suggest storing the data as a numeric or integer number of seconds (or milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

That data type is called an "interval" (the difference between 2 timestamps) and while it exists as a datatype in Redshift it is not a valid data type for storing in a table (intermediate results only).  So you have 2 choices - you can store this as a string and parse it on read OR you can store the info in seconds.  I recommend (just like Gordon) you choose the 2nd method (seconds).  This will be the easiest to work with and you can output they kinds of information you want by taking the value, converting it to interval seconds and then cast the interval to a string.